Using asyncio or multiprocessing in Python correctly
I need to convert a bunch of .xlsx files to PDF files. I use Linux mint and I wrote a script that does the job correctly if processing is done sequentially. However this takes a lot of time and I would like to speed up the things by running concurrently. The idea is to split a list of files needed to be converted in half and do these concurrently and independently. This should work since files are independent from each other.
I tried to use asyncio for this purpose and asked ChatGPT for help, but I cannot solve the problem, because randomly about 10 files (number varies) out of 100
just fail to convert to PDF.
I need your help to understand what is going on.
The original script used the following approach and it works slowly, but correctly:
def convert_pdf_soffice(xlsx_file: str)->None:
    out_dir = './PdfDir/'
    print('Started conversion of ', xlsx_file)
    subprocess.run(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', out_dir, xlsx_file])
    print('Finished conversion of ', xlsx_file)

I called the convert function in a loop, like this:
  for file in xls_files_to_be_converted:
       convert_pdf_soffice(file)

The concurrent approach is the following:
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import asyncio
import time

async def convert_pdf_soffice(xlsx_files):
    out_dir = './PdfDir/'
    tasks = []

    for xlsx_file in xlsx_files:
        print('Started conversion of ', xlsx_file)
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', out_dir, xlsx_file,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
        )
        tasks.append(process)

    for task, xlsx_file in zip(tasks, xlsx_files):
        stdout, stderr = await task.communicate()
        if task.returncode != 0:
            print(f'Conversion of {xlsx_file} failed with return code {task.returncode}')
        else:
            print('Finished conversion of ', xlsx_file)

async def main():
    start_t = time.time()

    INPUT_DIR = './XLSX/'
    OUTPUT_DIR = './PdfDir/'

    # Create folder if not exists
    if not os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR):
        os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR)

    # List of all xlsx files
    xlsx_file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]

    # Split the list into two halves
    mid_index = len(xlsx_file_list) // 2
    first_half = xlsx_file_list[:mid_index]
    second_half = xlsx_file_list[mid_index:]

    # List of xlsx files to be converted to pdf
    first_half_paths = [os.path.join(INPUT_DIR, file) for file in first_half]
    second_half_paths = [os.path.join(INPUT_DIR, file) for file in second_half]

    # Run conversions concurrently for both halves
    await asyncio.gather(
        convert_pdf_soffice(first_half_paths),
        convert_pdf_soffice(second_half_paths)
    )

    end_t = time.time()
    duration_t = end_t - start_t
    print(f'Duration is {duration_t}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


Are you sure soffice is able to run multiple instances concurrently?

Anyway, if your task is I/O-bound, you will only create congestion by creating multiple processes which fight each other for the available I/O bandwidth.

You might have better luck using Excel-opener and PDF-converter libraries in Python (there are several) instead of calling out to soffice.

Any suggestion?
unconv does not work as intended.

Using traditional multiprocessing it's just:
from pathlib import Path
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import subprocess

INPUT_DIR = Path("~/Documents").expanduser()
OUTPUT_DIR = Path("~/PdfDir").expanduser()
SOFFICE = Path("/Applications/Utilities/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice")

def convert(xl: Path) -> str:
    args = [
        str(SOFFICE),
        "--headless",
        "--convert-to",
        "pdf",
        "--outdir",
        str(OUTPUT_DIR),
        str(xl)
    ]

    try:
        r = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, check=True)
        return f"{xl} converted successfully" if r.returncode == 0 else r.stderr.decode()
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Exception processing {xl} -> {e}"

def main():
    OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for rv in exe.map(convert, INPUT_DIR.glob("*.xlsx")):
            print(rv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


soffice is the LibreOffice executable.

Leaving this here as it shows a reasonable approach to multiprocessing generally. However, it appears that it does not work in this particular case because soffice doesn't support multiple concurrent instances of itself. See here

Since you are actually running a shell command, instead of doing this in Python, I would simply use GNU Parallel.  Maybe something like this?
parallel soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir PdfDir {} ::: XLSX/*.xlsx

If you want to limit the number of parallel jobs, say to 2, you can do parallel -P2 <command>.
Explanation: The files matching *.xlsx are replaced wherever the command has {}. There are other more advanced replacement patterns, see the manual for that.

yes, this works after i installed parallel with sudo apt install. How ever I-d like to troubleshoot and understand why multiprocessing approach doesn't work.

Edit: It works only with P2 parameter. If P3 or P4 is used, then, essentially same problem appears like in Python multiprocessing example.

@AdenDenitz you don't mention what is the error, hard to suggest without any input. parallel in itself doesn't do anything special, so I would guess that you are hitting some kind of soffice limitation.

@AdenDenitz I tried it with the files you shared on Google drive, I don't see errors. I guess you mean it does 2 at a time. The -Pn parameter won't magically increase the number of threads. It depends on the number of cores on your CPU. I tried it on my laptop & desktop, and there I get 2 & 3 at a time respectively. You can try looking at other options for GNU parallel that allows you to tune this, but there will be an upper threshold.

@suvayuWhen I executed thew following command:
parallel -P4 soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ./PdfDir {} ::: XLSX/*.xlsx
i also didn't see errors, but I found for example only 75 files in my output directory, while there are 108 in original XLSX folder.
I repeated the same with more input xlsx files and also in that case I found that 20-30% of files are not converted.

@AdenDenitz you are right, something fishy is going on. I see the same behaviour. I'll investigate further.

No, this mp approach doesn't work either. It produces exceptions randomly and thus some files are not converted.
This is how I modified the script to be executed in my Linux Mint environment:
from pathlib import Path
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import subprocess
import time

INPUT_DIR = Path("./XLSX/").expanduser()
OUTPUT_DIR = Path("./PdfDir/").expanduser()
SOFFICE = Path("/usr/bin/soffice")


def convert(xl: Path) -> str:
    args = [
        str(SOFFICE),
        "--headless",
        "--convert-to",
        "pdf",
        "--outdir",
        str(OUTPUT_DIR),
        str(xl)
    ]

    try:
        r = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, check=True)
        return f"{xl} converted successfully" if r.returncode == 0 else r.stderr.decode()
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Exception processing {xl} -> {e}"

def main():
 
    start_t = time.time()
    OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for rv in exe.map(convert, INPUT_DIR.glob("*.xlsx")):
            print(rv)
    
    end_t = time.time()
    duration_t = end_t - start_t
    print(f'Duration is {duration_t}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here is the sample data if anyone is interested:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YSpeM2SCv3wavl-k65w2n4gaOZBGb98d/view?usp=sharing

It seems that multiple concurrent instances of soffice is a known problem. See this

yes, that is true, I even tried with parallel soffice and it works ok if called with P2. If called with P3 or P4, the same problem arises.

Interesting enough, this code works perfectly in NUM_PROC i.e. if file list is split into two parts and two processes are employed. Total time of execution is about half of original sequential. That is sufficient.
If  try to set NUM_PROC to  or 4 there are occasianlly exceptions and some files are not converted. It seems that this is the limit of soffice and not multiprocessing issue in the python itself.
import os
import subprocess
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


INPUT_DIR = './XLSX/'
OUTPUT_DIR = './PdfDir/'
NUM_PROC = 2

def convert_pdf_soffice(xlsx_files):
    for file in xlsx_files:
        print('Started conversion of ', file)
        try:
            r = subprocess.run(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', OUTPUT_DIR, file],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                check=True)
            print(f'{file} converted successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception processing {file} -> {e}')
   

def main():
    start_t = time.time()

    # Create folder if not exists
    os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR,exist_ok=True)

    # List all xlsx files
    xlsx_file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]
    # Calculate approximate chunk size
    chunk_size = len(xlsx_file_list) // NUM_PROC
    remainder = len(xlsx_file_list) % NUM_PROC  # Remainder for uneven division

    chunks = []
    start = 0

    for proc_id in range(NUM_PROC):
        if proc_id < remainder:
            # Include an extra file in this chunk if there's a remainder
            chunk = xlsx_file_list[start:start + chunk_size + 1]
            start += chunk_size + 1
        else:
            chunk = xlsx_file_list[start:start + chunk_size]
            start += chunk_size

        chunks.append(chunk)

    # List of xlsx files to be converted to pdf for each chunk
    chunk_paths = [[os.path.join(INPUT_DIR, file) for file in chunk] for chunk in chunks]

    # Create processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(NUM_PROC):
        p = mp.Process(target=convert_pdf_soffice, args=[chunk_paths[i]])
        p.start()
    
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()

    end_t = time.time()
    duration_t = end_t - start_t
    print(f'Duration is {duration_t}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

